# can we make use of youtube api for making it to pause at different point and use buttons for the pause points to playback at the pause points

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

hey friends i need little help on code where:

- I have video of 20mins
- I played for 5mins..I paused..So I call this as Tag1
- I played for another 5mins..I paused. So now video duration is 10mins
  competed...So this I call is Tag2
- I played for another 5 mins..I paused/ So now vide duration is 15mins
  completed..so this I call as Tag3.
- Now, When I click Button/link called Tag1..The video should directly
  start fron 5th min
- And when I click on button/link called Tag2, the video should
  directly start from 10th min
- And when I click on button/link called Tag2, the video should
  directly start from 15h min

i have tried but some help guys waiting for your reply

Comment: anyone there reply please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe create a script that works similar to this where it adds and seeks the paused moments depending on the ordered they were pushed into an array. This is a rough idea on how it would work:

```
    var player;
    var cid = [];
    var index = 0;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video', {
            events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event){
        $("#pause").on('click', function() {
            player.pauseVideo();
            cid.push(player.getCurrentTime());
        });
        $("#seek").on('click', function() {
            if (cid.length > 0 && index < cid.length) {
                player.seekTo(cid[index]);
                index++;
            }
            else {
                index=0;
                player.seekTo(cid[index]);
                index++;
            }
        });
```